# label text wont change before thread sleeps?

Tags: c#, label

im trying to change the text of my label then have a delay before the next form opens. but the label text wont change and just waits?

```
label3.Text = "loading tools";
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Form4 frm = new Form4();
        frm.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

Comment: What happens if you call `this.Refresh();` immediately after changing the label? However, the right way to approach this kind of thing nowadays is to use `await Task.Delay(2000)`.

Comment: Generally, this kind of stuff should be done with multithreading. Make a new thread loading the mentioned tools, and make said thread create the `Form4` when it's done and do an `Invoke` call to close the current form. _Never_ block your UI thread, especially not with a blatant `Thread.Sleep()`. It makes the program freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Add Application.DoEvents() after changing label text:

```
label3.Text = "loading tools";
Application.DoEvents();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Form4 frm = new Form4();
frm.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Comment: I don't recommend using `Application.DoEvents()` - it can cause nasty re-enterancy.

Answer (score 0):

label3.Text = "loading tools";

label3.Refresh();

Thread.Sleep(2000);

Form4 frm = new Form4();

frm.Show();

this.Hide();